# How should the `crypto` kernel parameter be passed?

Tags: linux, boot, dm-crypt, disk-encryption, kernel-parameters

1. I've encrypted a root drive using a cipher with this format:
   `<cipher>-<chainmode>-<ivmode>:<ivopt>`.
   Let's call this `[CIPHER]` for short.
2. To boot from this device, [certain encryption kernel parameters](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#Boot_loader) must be passed including `crypto`, because I'm using dm-crypt with plain encryption (no LUKS). `crypto` must have the following format:
   `crypto=<hash>:[CIPHER]:<keysize>:<offset>:<skip>`.
3. In my case, `[CIPHER]` contains a colon, so I cannot append the following to the kernel line:
   `crypto=<hash>:[CIPHER]:<keysize>:<offset>:<skip>`,
   because the syntax is invalidated and booting will fail.

My Question: Can I put double quotes around `[CIPHER]` to make it work? i.e. the following:
 `crypto=<hash>:"[CIPHER]":<keysize>:<offset>:<skip>`